# Getting "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch

Here is my code:

```js
const userIds: string[] = [
    // Squall
    '226618912320520192',

    // Tofu
    '249855890381996032',

    // Alex
    '343201768668266496',

    // Jeremy
    '754681236236140666',

    // Maddo
    '711211838305599538',

    // Arden
    '375573674306306050',

    // Neo
    '718874307316678698',

    // Mytho
    '480092510505402380',

    // Yuun
    '630427600220717067'
];
```

```js
const fetchData = async() => {
    let users: User[] = [];
    for (const id in userIds) {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=http://hamsterland.herokuapp.com/api/users?id=' + id);
        const user: User = await response.json(); 
        users.push(user);
    }
}
```

I get the error `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input`.

If I the API with each Id respectively, all return valid JSON. However, it does not work in the `for` loop.

Comment: You should check `repsonse.ok` before attempting to `response.json()` it. You are missing a `try/catch` around the code that can throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is the index, not the actual value. all you need to do is instead of appending id, append userIds[id]

```js
const userIds = [
    // Squall
    '226618912320520192',

    // Tofu
    '249855890381996032',

    // Alex
    '343201768668266496',

    // Jeremy
    '754681236236140666',

    // Maddo
    '711211838305599538',

    // Arden
    '375573674306306050',

    // Neo
    '718874307316678698',

    // Mytho
    '480092510505402380',

    // Yuun
    '630427600220717067'
];

const fetchData = async() => {
    let users = [];
    for (const id in userIds) {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=http://hamsterland.herokuapp.com/api/users?id=' + userIds[id]);
        const user = await response.json(); 
        users.push(user);
    }
    return users;
}

fetchData().then(ele => console.log(ele)).catch(e => console.log(e.message))
```

Unrelated to the current problem, await in a for loop is not a good practice. awaiting in a for loop waits for each call to finish before executing the next call.
Using, Promise.all will make all the calls concurrently.
Below is a snippet for the Promise.all.

```
const fetchData = async() => {
    let users = [];
    for (const id in userIds) {
        users.push(fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=http://hamsterland.herokuapp.com/api/users?id=' + userIds[id]));
    }
    const results = await Promise.all(users);
    return Promise.all(results.map(result => result.json()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply do

```
for (const id in userIds) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

you'll see the problem. In this loop, `id` are *keys*, not *values*. You probably get `404`s in return.

Use a `for... of` loop instead of `for... in`.